# iPhone development - How to get some device [usage] info/statistics

Tags: iphone, statistics, device, uidevice

So, I know that is possible to retrieve some info, like Device name, unique ID, etc. all of them provided by [UIDevice Class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

I would like to know if there is a way to get information related with wireless usage (Download and upload), amount of SMS sent, minutes of talking, and any other statistics.

Does anyone has any idea on how to get this info?

Cheers,

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple doesn't allow this unless the phone is jailbroken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AFAIK you can't get that information using public APIs. But, just as a side note, the application below shows how to access different kinds of "supposedly private" information in the iPhone by using public APIs:

http://github.com/nst/SpyPhone

Comment: Hey Adrian, thanks for that! Your answer is correct, until Apple release a framework or a way to we have access to this restrict info.